# Compute separate Zonal Statistics table for one raster, zones are many polygons in shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

Seems earlier ArcMap versions made this possible:

I have one raster (pixels are landcover classes) and a set of buffers stored as multiple polygons (possibly overlapping) in a polygon shapefile.

Using Zonal Statistics as Table, I specify these files as input raster and zone field, respectively. Produces one zonal statistics table for the total area covered by all ploygons in the shapefile.

Is is possible, *without scripting*, to compute and store one zonal statistics table for *each* polygon in the shapefile?

If scripting is necessary, what is the latest ArcMap scripting environment called and is there a tutorial demonstrating how to solve this problem?

Comment: Zonal Statistics as Table http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w8000000 then join the table to the polygons. Seems to me that you're using Zonal Statistics incorrectly, you should be able to get each polygon as separate statistics provided you use the polygons as polygons and don't convert to raster first. The current scripting for ArcGis is arcpy http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000v000000v7000000

Comment: If polygons overlap, scripting is the only option, unless the raster is not huge, you can convert it to points and intersect with polygons. Have a look http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112946/zonal-statistics-for-millions-of-overlapping-polygons/112947#112947

Comment: Check if zone field stores unique values

Answer (score 2):

Try exploding the polygon shapefile first.  If they are stored as a single multipart feature the statistics will be computed for the combined polygons.

Edit: missed the overlapping part of the question, but unless they are *all* overlapping then you should get statistics for each non-overlapping polygon.